# high score table stored in .txt

Tags: python, list, txt

[image: that's how it looks for now scull]

I marked blocks with comments

```
    score_two_func()*downolad stuff here*

table = []
high_score = 0

def add_high_score(new_high_score, player_name):   #here
    try:
        if game_over is True:
            high_score_file = open("high_score.txt", "a")
            high_score_file.seek(0)
            table.append(new_high_score)
            rec = max(table)
            high_score_file.write(player_name + ' ' + str(rec))
            high_score_file.write('\n')
            high_score_file.close()
    except IOError:
         print("Unable to save the high score.")

*etc functions*


while flag is True:
  *main code start*
    if score_one or score_two > high_score:  #and here 
            if score_one > score_two:
                score_m = score_one
                player_n = 'Player one'
            if score_two > score_one:
                score_m = score_two
                player_n = 'Player two'
            add_high_score(score_m, player_n)
    else:
        print("Better luck next time.")
    pygame.display.update()
*main code over*
quit()
```

*Hello, I can not make a table of records. At the moment, ~300 identical lines have been written to the document. I still need to figure out how to sort them.
*

Comment: How about using a class and then pickle that rather rather than a text file?

Comment: Use `shelve` and you can have a persistent database that is extremely simple to work with. Storing databases in a text file and then manually parsing specific data is a terrible design. It's also unnecessary. CSV, JSON, PKL, SQL... there a bunch of options that are already built for this, why are you trying to invent one? You could delete all your code and rewrite it better in about 4 lines. Also, your alleged comments are not comments, at all. All you did was break your code.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do and what the problem is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: didn't put it that way, 300 lines of code come out in one game session, when in fact there should be one and I don’t understand what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.splitlines` to get a list of every single line in the file. Then by indexing on specific parts of the lines (ex. on index 7 if its "o" because of "one" it's player one score if its "t" its player)
If you want to sort the scores you can index to 11, where the score is located and append it to a list as an integer
`<your list>.append(int(<splited file>[11]))` and then sort it using `<your list>.sort()`